# How do I show nodes/articles with specific taxonomy on a page?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 7, search

Maybe the title is not appropriate, so please dont hesitate to change it or give suggestions for it.

Here's how our Drupal site is done:

A vocabulary called "`PAA`".
With this vocabulary there are many terms organized like this:

```
PAA
  |
  \-- MainTerm01
  |   |
  |   \-- SubTerm01
  |   |
  |   \-- SubTerm02
  |   |
  |   ...
  |   
  \-- MainTerm02
      |
      \-- SubTerm03
      |
      \-- SubTerm04
      |
      ...
```

Then we have tons of articles that are associated with only one `MainTermXX` and only one `SubTermXX` (whatever `XX` is).
Here's what we'd like to do: make a page where we can search for a term (either `MainTermXX` or `SubTermXX`) and display all articles that are associated with the term.

My question is: is there a way to do this easily (= is this native in Drupal, just configuration) or will I have some work to do about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) for building the output of the page and filtering according to the search query (that is called "exposed filter" in views).

To get familiar with Views and see all what you can do with them, check out [Nodeone library of videos on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/nodeone/videos).

Comment: So what I'm asking for should be easy to do, it's just about configuring Drupal properly?

Comment: Yes. This does not require you to write any code. The only thing you have to do is to install Views and learn how to use them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've created a view that works but the resulting query is 18 lines long with 3 joins, whereas the module I've developped with a hook_node has a query of one line with one join. Well Drupal is powerful for beginners but far more powerful for developpers **`;)`**